# Yii - using MySQL AS clause field

Tags: mysql, yii, custom-fields, customcolumn, cactivedataprovider

Let's say I want to have a provide CActiveDataProvider for a CGridView. I need to put a `SUM(invitesCount) AS invites` into a Provider result. How to retrieve it? I guess I cannot just use `$dataProvider->invites`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the following in your relationinvites

```
'invites '=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'CampaignFund', 'campaign_id', 'select' => 'SUM(invitesCount)'),
```

and use this relation in your criteria.

Comment: Thank you. Is it good idea to add realtions every time we need some field? Is that efficient? I noticed seconds before read your answer I can just define new public properties and do the select with `AS` pointint to those properties. Not sure which way is the better one?

Answer (score 1):

Several other options:

1. Use [CStatRelation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#statistical-query)

   ```
   invitesCount=>array(self::STAT,'Invites','foreign_key_field');
   ```
2. The addition of a public property can work. However, the field would only be set if you altered the default find query to include this new condition. This can be done by overriding [`defaultScope()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.0/CActiveRecord#defaultScope-detail) or creating a new [`scope`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.0/CActiveRecord#scopes-detail) and using it whenever `invitesCount` is required.
3. Another option would be to create a database view from the required query and create a new Model from that database view.

Comment: Actually you don't have to define new `scope`. You can simply change `search` method to accept `CDbCriteria` object as a parameter with default value `null` and then merge default criteria with criteria from parameter.